# Kid's fillings pick up radio signals, he makes contact with aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

This novel was written in kind of tongue-in-cheek IIRC.

Like I said in the question header, the protagonist has a dental filling which somehow starts acting as a radio receiver, eventually through it he learns of approaching aliens who intend to plunder Earth but "won't do anything destructive (yeah, I'm not sure how they're supposed to pull that off either)."

The aliens in question all look like fat humans with glasses (I think on the cover they all look like the same fat man with glasses} in tacky suits.

It was written in English, I recall reading it somewhen in the early-mid 80's but it could've been published before then.

Comment: This sounds slightly familiar, but more information would really help.  When did you read this?  How old was it when you read it? What language was the book in?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Fat Men From Space, by Daniel Pinkwater](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/888410.Fat_Men_from_Space)

[image]

It doesn't mention the part about the fillings in the Goodreads description from what I saw, but it was mentioned in another review blurb I found:

> Another silly story from Daniel Pinkwater, this one about a boy whose new dental filling enables to receive radio signals in his mouth, resulting in his unwitting discovery of an invasion of earth by Fat Men from Space who want all of our snack foods - especially potato pancakes. Great fun, as always.

Comment: ^_^ I almost posted a story-id question about this one a few years ago before finding it myself. Yes, he picks up radio transmissions via his fillings (a known thing to happen in real-life) with him finding that touching different pieces of metal to the filling changes the station. The finds out about the aliens when he attempts using a chain-link fence as a huge antenna.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots- Actually I almost submitted this question sooner, but I was worried it would turn out to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Nu'Daq
No shame in a duplicate. Great minds and all of that.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots- No shame? Never know it from my Doctor Who question.